# Can I get reputation without giving any answer to question or without asking any question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, association-bonus

I have just seen the profile of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220428/qantas-94-heavy.

This person has not asked any question and not given any answer but he has 101 rep. How's that?

Comment: You can see all reputation changes in the user's [reputation tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220428/qantas-94-heavy?tab=reputation), the +100 is there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case - association bonus.

If you have an account on any Stack Exchange site with over 200 reputation, you will get a +100 association bonus on other, linked sites.

Another way to get reputation without asking or answering is to suggest edits. Every approved suggested edit gives +2 reputation to a [maximum total of +1000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Comment: Maximum is 1000 from suggested edits, unless it was changed?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - wasn't changed. Working from (corrupt?) memory.

Comment: `chkdsk` then? ;) Fixed the corruption then and added link to more details. :)